# Is there easier way to check whether the re.sub() replaced the word or not in python?

Tags: python

I am learning regex of python.

I would like to check the words in a file are replaced by re.sub() function.

```
import re

original_file=open('original_file_path','r')
replaced_file=open('replaced_file_path','w')

compiled_pattern=re.compile('target_pattern')

match_flag=False
for line in original_file:
    new_line=re.sub(compiled_pattern, 'new_pattern', line, flags=0)
    replaced_file.write(new_line)

    search_result=re.search(compiled_pattern, new_line)
    if search_result:
        match_flag=True

original_file.close()
replaced_file.close()

if match_flag:
    print("Some parts are replaced")
```

My code above uses re.search() but I am afraid that it is redundant because re.sub and re.search scans the same 'line' independently.
 Are there any easier way to check whether the words in the file are really replaced or not? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [re.subn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn):

> `re.subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> Perform the same operation as `sub()`, but return a tuple `(new_string, number_of_subs_made)`.

For example:

```
>>> r = re.compile('a')
>>> s = 'aaaaa'
>>> (x,n) = re.subn(r, 'b', s)
>>> n
5
>>> x
'bbbbb'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can compare old with new string

```
if new_line != line:
  match_flag=True
```